# java: generating a properties file that contains the svn version number

Tags: svn, ant

I want to generate a properties file, from my ant script, that contains the svn version number of my project. I'm 1/3 of the way done:

To do this I need to:

1. use svnversion

   1a. [define the svn task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html)

   1b. use [`<svn><wcVersion></svn>`](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html#wcVersion)
2. put the result in a .properties file that ends up in my build path

I'm a bit lost with 1a and 2. any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

never mind, I got it working:

```
<target name="svnversion">
  <echo file="${srcDir}/${packagePath}/svnversion.properties">svnversion=</echo>
  <exec executable="svnversion"
      output="${srcDir}/${packagePath}/svnversion.properties" append="true">
  </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 3):

What I used is to execute `svn info --xml`, then loaded the resulted xml file using [`<XmlProperty>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) and in the end just replacing a token in the property file that is path of the build path.

So something like this:

```
<target name="svn-build-number">
  <tempfile property="svninfo.file"/>
  <exec dir="." executable="svn" output="${svninfo.file}">
    <arg line="info --xml"/>
  </exec>
  <echo message="${svninfo.file}" />
  <xmlproperty file="${svninfo.file}" collapseAttributes="true" />
  <echo message="${info.entry.revision}" />
</target>
```

In `${info.entry.revision}` is the revision of the repository in the current dir.

Comment: instead of temp. file, you can use a property:
 <exec executable="svn" outputproperty="svninfo.xml">
        <arg line="info --xml"/>
    </exec>
    <xmlproperty collapseAttributes="true">
      <propertyresource name="svninfo.xml"/>
    </xmlproperty>
    <echo message="${info.entry.revision}" />